# Finding the count of numbers divisible by either of 3 values. How can it be more optimised

Tags: c++, division

Three positive nos. A,B,C.Find no. of pos integers less than D divisible by either a,b,c. Well the test cases ran fine with one but for submitting it needed more optimised code. How can it be more optimised?

```
solve(int A, int B, int C, int D) {
    int X = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < D; i++)
    {
        if (i%A==0 || i%B==0 || i%C==0)
        {
            X++;
        }
    }
    return X;
}
```

Comment: Can't it be done in constant time? If you divide two numbers and floor the result (automatic if you use integers), you should get what you need. Trick is how to not count the same numbers twice, so you'll have to figure out what's in common (if at all) between A,B,C.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple take any number ,let it be 11,to find how many numbers are divisible by 3 we just need to find 11/3=3 i.e 3,6,9
Hence we add all the elements that are divisible by A or B or C.
But we also find that numbers like 24 are divisible by both 3 and 4 hence they will be counted twice if A=3 and B=4  so we subtract the amount that are divisible by both,i.e the ones divisible by lcm(3,4)=12. Similarly for the numbers divisible by all three should be added as it was subtracted multiple times.

Code is...

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


int lcm(int a, int b);
int gcd(int a, int b);


int solve(int A,int B,int C,int D)
 {
  int divisibleA=D/A;                    //positive Numbers divisible by A
  int divisibleB=D/B;
  int divisibleC=D/C;

  int divisible_A_B= D/(lcm(A,B));          //positive numbers that were divisible by A and B both These were counted twice
  int divisible_A_C= D/(lcm(A,C));
  int divisible_B_C= D/(lcm(B,C));

  int divisible_A_B_C=D/lcm(lcm(A,B),C);     //positive numbers divisible by all three


    return  divisibleA+divisibleB+divisibleC-divisible_A_B-divisible_A_C-divisible_B_C+ divisible_A_B_C;
}


int main()
{
 int a,b,c,d;
 cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
 cout<<solve(a,b,c,d)<<endl;
}

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
 // base case
   if (a == b)
    return a;

  // a is greater
 if (a > b)
     return gcd(a-b, b);
 return gcd(a, b-a);
}

// Function to return LCM of two numbers
int lcm(int a, int b)
{
 return (a*b)/gcd(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: The following should work:

```
int solve(const std::vector &array_of_numbers, int size, int divider){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if (array_of_numbers.at(i)%divider == 0){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This is C++!  Might as well use `std::vector`

Comment: This one will result in O(n) time complexity, while there exists a solution in O(1) TC